# How to exclude individual file in module from maven deploy

Tags: maven

I'm using maven deploy to upload the module into Nexus
I would like to know if there is the way to exclude individual file from module on maven deployment stage from command line

Thanks
Lena

Comment: What kind of individual file? How are you calling Maven?

Comment: I'm using the following command: mvn -gs cfg/maven/ci/settings.xml -Ddocker.image.release=0753 -pl pod-category-exe clean deploy . In the log I see the following :                                                                                                  [Build] [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.0.2:jar (default-jar) @ pod-category-exe ---
[Build] [INFO] Building jar: /users/admin/workspace/pod-category-ms/pod-category-exe/target/pod-category-exe-0.1.0-0753.jar
[Build] [INFO] 

[Build] [INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ pod-category-exe ---

Comment: The question is if there is way to cancel jar building stage or to cancel the stage of deploy this jar

Comment: Can you show the full pom file? Furthermore you are deploying only a child module of a multi module build. Why are you using `-gs ..` not configured correctly in environment ?

Comment: I want to deploy only child module , but I don't want that jar  will be created .[Build] [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.0.2:jar (default-jar) @ pod-category-exe --- [Build] [INFO] Building jar: /users/admin/workspace/pod-category-ms/pod-category-exe/targ‌​et/pod-category-exe-‌​0.1.0-0753.jar

Comment: without the pom files it's hard. BTW: What is the real problem with that jar file?